# Performance of Vaadin LitTemplates for basic html Table component

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, lit-element

The Vaadin [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid#component-vs-lit-renderer-flow-only) states:

- "Component renderers are easy to build, but slow to render."
- "Lit renders quickly, but requires you to write HTML code."

The context for this is the Vaadin Grid component, and in reference to renderers. I can't find documentation that clearly explains the performance ramifications of LitTemplate vs
Java components *outside* the context of Grid Renderers.

My Scenario:

I have a view that uses the base html Table element (out of necessity). This table(s) has hundreds of rows and 10-20 columns, so potentially thousands of cells, and is *not* lazy loaded. The entire table needs to be rendered, and thus performance is a concern. The table is mostly table/tr/td/div/span elements, and right now is completely constructed via Java. The page is slow to render (10+ seconds at times) and so Im forced to use a progress bar to indicate that to the user. There is very little IO/logic on the server. The entire contents of the table are fetched from the database prior to constructing the UI. So I can isolate the performance of the UI creation, and I am confident that the "slowness" is due to the number of components being pushed to the client.

So my questions are...

- How does the component/lit difference apply here?
- Would it still be faster to create a combined LitTemplate class for the table cell? Or
  are those html element java classes already using Lit & sub templates
  under the hood? I know Vaadin devs said they were transitioning all
  components to Lit.
- I'm confused as to why the basic components dont
  extend LitTemplate whenever the components have supposedly been
  migrated to Lit from Polymer?

Comment: 10+ seconds sounds slow to me. I have made HTML table component fully in Java, and the rendering speed sounds better than yours, you can check it here: https://v-herd.eu/tatulund-addons/beantable

Comment: @TatuLund That table doesn't have 2000 cells, and is lazy loaded. I have to render the entire table to the page.

Comment: I tried it with 20 cols x 200 rows, and then it took 2-3 sec to render.

Comment: @TatuLund Can you send me the link? I dont see any way to set the page size/columns in your demo.

Comment: @TatuLund I should also point out that your content is simple text. The content of each of my table cells is div->x3span->x3span. So 9+ sub elements per cell. And in many cases it's 15 elements depending on the underlying data. So it's not an accurate comparison. For your demo to match you would need to use ComponentRenderers, which IME are *much* slower than raw html elements.

Comment: That is quite a lot elements in the DOM.  You can test BeanTable with something similar using this code https://gist.github.com/TatuLund/55896017829b81d3523c22a24af6d4b9

Comment: @TatuLund It may be a lot for *Vaadin* to render, but in general, thousands of elements is not that big of a deal for a DOM. Once rendered they get to the browser it can scroll and jump around with no problem.

Comment: I made an example using LitRenderer with Grid as well https://gist.github.com/TatuLund/dfac4424d1756f14a68d2a047c680234 which is actually pretty snappy as Grid does lazy loading here (i.e. all rows are not rendered at once, only the visible).

Comment: @TatuLund Unfortunately the requirement is that this cannot be lazy loaded. All rows must be present on the page.

Comment: Why don't you write both (or rahter the "lit" version) and benchmark them? If I tell you, that client side rendering is faster, will you believe a stranger from the internet?

Comment: @cfrick Ultimately that is probably what I will do.

Comment: And if this is just dumb data to display, then also consider, creating the html on the server with a template library, send the string to some lit-or-whatever-component and just "render" it by setting the innerHTML.

Comment: @cfrick It would be great if I could get Vaadin to render the entire block as raw HTML on the server side and send it that way, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @cfrick I can say for certain that Vaadin Grid with ComponentRender is definitely not better, because that's what I used prior to the basic html components.

Comment: Using new Html should be pretty fast because it's just parsing with jsoup and getting the top most element and the other content is added with innerHtml. (Speaking from experience, creating huge pages with it)

Comment: @Knoobie, yes generating the table as String in Java and using Html should be fast approach as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think one factor here is the build-up of quite some useless state
(nodes in the UI StateTree).  Then all this state gets sent to the
client, and it has to create the DOM from it.  The more "smart" tags you
are using, the more work is to be done in the client as well.

If your data is just dumb HTML (no need to interact, no need to change,
...) then you could as well just generate the HTML code on the server
and then use either `Html` (which will parse your HTML with Jsoup each time
you create an instance and create a component from it) or just
use a dumb client-side component to just render an HTML string.

Below example is for comparing the speed (times are according to FX dev-console,
what is reported as "Finished" at the end of the network tab, YMMV):

- the `vaadin` route takes here about 130ms
- the `dumb` route takes here about 60ms

Client-side: `./frontend/DumbHtml.ts`:

```js
import {html, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {unsafeHTML} from 'lit/directives/unsafe-html.js';

class DumbHtml extends LitElement {

    static properties = {
        html: {}
    }

    protected render(): unknown {
        return html`${unsafeHTML(this.html)}`;
    }
}

customElements.define('dumb-html', DumbHtml);
```

Server-side: (somewhere in your `src` dir)

```
@Route('vaadin')
class VaadinHtmlView extends Div implements AfterNavigationObserver {
    @Override
    void afterNavigation(AfterNavigationEvent event) {
        removeAll()
        add(new Html(HTML.build()))
    }
}

@Tag('dumb-html')
@JsModule('./DumbHtml.ts')
class DumbHtml extends LitTemplate {
    DumbHtml(String html) {
        element.setProperty('html', html)
    }
}

@Route('dumb')
class DumbHtmlView extends Div implements AfterNavigationObserver {
    @Override
    void afterNavigation(AfterNavigationEvent event) {
        removeAll()
        add(new DumbHtml(HTML.build()))
    }
}

class HTML {
    @Memoized
    static String build() {
        def sw = new StringWriter()
        def builder = new MarkupBuilder(sw)
        builder.table {
            tbody {
                (0..200).each {
                    tr {
                        (0..20).each {
                            td {
                                (0..9).each {
                                    span(it)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        sw.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html ?

Comment: You could define such simple web component also in Java -> https://gist.github.com/TatuLund/d20bb975e17b303d84b5f59dce9deaa5

Comment: @TatuLund Yes.  The code is tagged accordingly, but I guess there is no
way to make SO tell about it.

Comment: @TatuLund Sure, if the shadow DOM is needed. I assumed no performance
influence for either so I did not try to make them both behave exactly
the same.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the component/lit difference apply here?

I assume you mean Java server side composition vs. Lit based component.

When you do the component as Java server side composition, the element tree is sent as JSON type data to Vaadin's Flow client running in the browser runtime. That will decode the data, and build corresponding DOM using normal JavaScript calls.

When you create the component using Lit, that will mean that the component DOM instructions are in the render function of it. This Lit file is compiled from TypeScript to JavaScript and included into frontend bundle during build time. However, in this case you need to populate the component with data by some means. Typically you need to have property, e.g. JSON array and set it run time. Lit and Browser will generate the web component when application is initialized. The render function usually executes faster than building the DOM by reading the instructions from the JSON by Flow client.

Naturally the first method have some overhead, which may or may not be significant depending on the case. The JSON data with both component tree info and data is a bit larger than mere JSON data array you use to populate the component.

> Would it still be faster to create a combined LitTemplate class for the table cell?

Yes, it will be probably faster. But it really depends on the priorities. For example the mentioned BeanTable component performs in some use cases almost as fast as Grid. It depends also on the target browser. E.g. BeanTable can be faster in Firefox, as Grid has slot for each cell, which are populated by the data sent from the server. Firefox is bad in slotting, and hence the data population is actually slower than the first mentioned decoding JSON and generating table by that process. On the other hand Chrome is very fast in slotting and Grid performs better. Now if you want even faster performance than Grid, you can create highly specific custom Lit based table component for your application. This will be have more impact with Firefox, if you decide not to have slots in cells, but e.g. just populate inner text attribute of the cells. With Chrome the difference is much less.

See [blog post](https://vaadin.com/blog/creating-a-custom-component-with-lit) about writing Lit components for Vaadin.

> I know Vaadin devs said they were transitioning all components to Lit.

At the time of writing this our components are made with Polymer, but yes eventually they will be converted to Lit. However the performance difference Polymer vs. Lit is usually much less than server side composition vs Polymer/Lit.

> I'm confused as to why the basic components dont extend LitTemplate whenever the components have supposedly been migrated to Lit from Polymer?

Just noting, the use of Java `LitTemplate` class is not mandated if you create component with Lit. You need that only if you want to bind elements server side with `@Id` annotation.

Middle ground option would be just to use [LitRenderer](https://gist.github.com/TatuLund/dfac4424d1756f14a68d2a047c680234) in the Grid component.

```
        grid.addColumn(LitRenderer.<...> of("..")
                .withProperty("number",
                        item -> item.getNumber()));
```

Comment: Okay, so seems like I need to write a Lit component for at least the table cell, since that will reduce the number of server side components 10-15x, and see if that improves things. I think there's enough info in that blog to get that done.

Comment: The Grid with LitRenderer, using setAllRowsVisible and 200 rows based on the code I linked renders in 1.5secs. It is pretty fast.